# Expected value of number of steps in a random walk

Tags: probability, expectation, random-walk

Richard makes a random walk with 101 notes. 70 of which says go +1, 30 of which says go -1 and one says go back to starting point (which is denoted - 0). At each step, he picks one note randomly and moves accordingly (without returning the note).

Let $X$ be his location after taking out all the notes.

What is the expected value of $X$?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know how can I improve my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of going only right in a random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821378/probability-of-going-only-right-in-a-random-walk)

Comment: @lulu I actually based my question on this one.

Comment: I'll retract the close vote as the questions aren't exactly the same.  To handle this question note that you expect half of each type of motion card to follow the start over card.

Comment: @lulu Can you help me solve this one? I'm stuck for hours.

Comment: I gave you the solution.  You expect there to be $35$  "$+1$" cards and $15$ "$-1$" cards following the "start over" card, so the answer is $35-15=20$

Comment: If you want another argument (or at least a more formal version of the first argument), use Linearity of Expectation.  Each card has a $\frac 12$ chance of being played after the start over card (by symmetry).  Thus the expected move is half the sum of the card values, so $20$.